# how can i compare two values and rank them in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

how can i compare two values and rank them in excel
the largest value should be 1 and smallest be last

```
Category    amount  rank
abc            300     1
abc              6     3
abc             34     2
xyz             50     2
xyz            568     1
xyz              1     3
```

`I tried this by my own COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,$B:$B,">"&$B2)+COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,$A2,$B$2:$B2,$B2)`
its working 
but I want it in more simpler way.

Comment: is this fixed or dynamic data?

Comment: dynamic data, I Have just taken the example

Comment: COUNTIFS function will gonna work out,but i dont know how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`=SUM((B2<=$B$2:$B$15)*1*(A2=$A$2:$A$15))`

This is an array formula so commit by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: not getting a right answer :(

Comment: @poojasingh - Can you tell me what isn't right. I do understand that its in the rank but what exactly is the issue. Can you provide sample data.

Comment: its showing 1 for all the rows

Comment: @poojasingh - Its an array formula. After typing formula press Ctrl+Shift+Enter, not just Enter.

Comment: It works when u select the cell references in formula in the formula bar and then press ctrl+shift+enter,anyways thanks a lot :)

Comment: @poojasingh - so is it working?

Comment: yes it is working now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in cell `A2` you can use

```
{=MATCH(B2,LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$7=A2,$B$2:$B$7),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,A2)))),0)}
```

This is an array formula, so enter using `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER`.

Change `$A$2:$A$7` and `$B$2:$B$7` to your data range.

Comment: =COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,$B:$B,">"&$B2)+COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,$A2,$B$2:$B2,$B2) one way is this one...but i need it in more simpler way

Comment: If you have already tried this and it works, add it to your question with the example, explaining you need it simpler. But if that works why not just use that?

Comment: it worked,I gave this solution to my senior,but he's asking for simpler one

Comment: @poojasingh Simpler how? Edit the question so others might be able to help also, and describe what you mean by 'simpler'.